# taking absolute value of CGFloat

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

How can I do that? I tried the abs() but it only works for int's. Is there a built in way to do so?

```
CGFloat flo = -123;
abs(flo)
```

this returns 0

Comment: Standard 'abs' function works great In Swift 4

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use fabs()

```
CGFloat f = -123.4f;
CGFloat g = fabs(f);
```

`CGFloat` is defined as a `double` on 64-bit machines, and `float` on 32-bit machines.  If you are targeting both 64 and 32 bit than this answer gets more complicated, but is still correct.

You want to use `fabs()` because it works on `double` datatypes which are larger than `float`.  On 32-bit, assigning the return value of `fabs()` (which is a `double`) into a `CGFloat` (which is a `float`) is ok ONLY if you are taking the absolute value of a `CGFloat` or `float`. You would potentially overflow a 32-bit `CGFloat` if you try to store the absolute value of a large `double` number.  In short, 64-bit is fine, and on 32-bit don't mix and match `double` and `CGFloat` and you'll be fine.

The `ABS()` macro apparently can have side-effects on some compilers.

Comment: Correct (+1), but print the value or make an assignment.

Comment: CGFloat is a typedef for either float or double (32/64 bit system). fabs takes a double (at least in my xcode, that's what it wants). So would this be safe then?

Comment: fabs() takes a double, fabsf() takes a float and there's a long double one two. There are macros to determine whether CGFloat is a double or float.

Comment: As CGFloat could be defined as a double or a float, it's hard to say this is the right answer: fabsf expects a float as input parameter, fabs returns always a double. The usage of std::abs() or the macro ABS() should be suggested in a 32bit/64bit environment (like mobiles today).

Comment: This is no longer correct as of 64 bit iOS, you get a SEMANTIC ISSUE WARNING:

`Absolute value function 'fabsf' given an argument of type 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') but has parameter of type 'float' which may cause truncation of value`

Comment: Can you expand on your last comment about `ABS()` having side effects on some compilers? Which compilers? If I'm sticking to Xcode, is it completely safe?

Answer (score 9):

For 64/32 bit system

```
#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE
    CGFloat g = fabs(flo);
#else
    CGFloat g = fabsf(flo);
#endif
```

Comment: This is the best answer short of making your own macro wrapper. Other than this determine if you really do have any 32bit platform to worry about.

Comment: This is exactly what the predefined macro ABS is for as Skela said in another answer.

Answer (score 8):

I normally just use the ABS macro, as far as I can tell, it works regardless of which system you're on or which primitive you're using.

```
CGFloat x = -1.1;
double y = -2.1;
NSInteger z = -5;

x = ABS(x);
y = ABS(y);
z = ABS(z);
```

Answer (score 6):

Small addition:

```
CGFloat g = fabs(f);
```

This will result in a casting warning, because fabs() returns a double value.
To get a float value back, you need to use fabsf().

```
CGFloat g = fabsf(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fabs` is depreciated. The signature of `abs` is now generic with this signature

```swift
/// Returns the absolute value of the given number.
///
/// The absolute value of `x` must be representable in the same type. In
/// particular, the absolute value of a signed, fixed-width integer type's
/// minimum cannot be represented.
///
///     let x = Int8.min
///     // x == -128
///     let y = abs(x)
///     // Overflow error
///
/// - Parameter x: A signed number.
/// - Returns: The absolute value of `x`.
@inlinable public func abs<T>(_ x: T) -> T where T : Comparable, T : SignedNumeric
```